# null safe the laravel relationship object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have a `user` and a `profile` model that every user `hasOne` profile .
on some pages i wanted to check the profile of user field like below :

```
$user->profile->membership_id
```

now my application crashes when the `->profile` does not exists i can use null coalesce the `membership_id` but i want to know if its possible to null safe the `->profile` so if profile does not exists the application wont give error like below :

```
trying to get membership_id of none object
```

Comment: Check if `$user->profile` exists before calling `->membership_id`

Comment: `null safe` is available as of PHP 8: `$user->profile?->membership_id`: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator

Comment: any way to use it in php 7 ?

Comment: Why don't you use property_exists()? Edit: NVM Marcin Nabiałek got it.

Comment: @Farshad No, it's a new operator added in PHP 8, so you can't use it in PHP 7. There are other approaches (like `null coalesce` as you stated, and the answer below), but `null safe` will require you to update your PHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set default object adding [withDefault](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#default-models) to your relationship for example:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class)->withDefault();
}
```

or

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Profile::class)->withDefault(['name' => 'No profile']);
}
```

Comment: thanks man thats what i was looking for :)